# How to find out custom device screen size in points for Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: android, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I want to add Samsung Galaxy A50 in Chrome Dev Tools custom devices, I now its screen size in pixels, its PPI and etc. But dev tools want its width and height in pts (points)! How to figure out screen size of Galaxy A50 in pts?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the device pixel ratio. I'll use an iPhone 11 for an example, with a pixel ratio of 2 and a screen size of 828px by 1792px, the viewport size would be 414px by 896px. (828/2 = 414) (1792/2 = 896).

But how do you know the pixel ratio...can search around for that but a faster way to get the viewport info is to use a site like https://www.mydevice.io.